# Remove Part After Last Occurrence of a Word Pattern in a String

Tags: javascript, string

I have this code:

```
var str = 'country/city/area'
var idx = str.lastIndexOf('country/city')
// idx = 0
```

And *idx* is always 0. Shouldn't *idx* be 12? My goal is to use it substr() in order to take the string *'area'* out of the *str*.

Comment: lastIndexOf returns the first position index of the last occurrence of the string, meaning it's correct.

Comment: *"The lastIndexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the last occurrence of the specified value, searching backwards from fromIndex."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

Comment: Okay, I get it. But what can I do in my case, to get the last position index?

Comment: @pmqa are you looking for the last letter (a, in your example) or the last WORD?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lastIndexOf is working as intended and you need to read the documentation before asking what it should or should not be doing.

Comment: @dlamblin you're right. I misread the documentation. But the choosen answer definitely answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = 'country/city/area'
var pattern = 'country/city/'
var idx = str.lastIndexOf(pattern) + pattern.length
var substring = str.substring(idx, str.length)
```

## Explanation

1) Define the pattern you are searching for

2) Find the beginning of the pattern and add the length of the pattern => now you are at the end

3) Copy the part behind the pattern to the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the last word, you can search for the last forward slash and get everything after it:

```
    str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

if you want to get everything after 'country/city/' but for example you don't know if this the first part of the string, you can use

```
    str.substr(str.indexOf('country/city/') + 13);
```

it's not 100% clear from your question, what exactly you are trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to add the length of the string that you search for:

```
var str = 'country/city/area';
var checkStr = 'country/city';
var idx = str.lastIndexOf(checkStr);
var lastCharIndex = idx + checkStr.length;

// idx = 0
// idx = 12
```

**note** - it would be `12`, not `13`, because you didn't include the final "/" in your `lastIndexOf` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can achieve your goal as follows;

```js
var str = 'country/city/area',
 newStr = str.replace("/area","");
console.log(newStr);
```